# Is there a way to designate multiple image sources in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: html, image

Is there a way to tell the browser to look down a list of image URLs until it finds one that works?  Pure HTML would be preferred, but I'm guessing JavaScript is probably necessary here (I'm already using JQuery, so it's not an issue).

EDIT: Thanks for your answers!  I'll add a few clarifications:

1. By "works" I mean the image can be displayed.
2. I specifically want to do this on the client side.

Comment: No, but yes a JavaScript / JQuery solution is possible, a server-side solution is another option.

Comment: I think this link may help your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/a/9891041/2301588

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a bad idea to me.  What is the purpose of this feature?  It sounds like you want something equivalent to this:

```
<img src="/images/file1.jpg" src2="/images/file2.jpg" src3="/images/file3.jpg">
```

Where the browser would try each file in succession.  The problem with this approach is that it significantly increases the http traffic required and the latency.  The best approach is to dynamically construct the page using the correct image tags ahead of time.  Using a server-side approach you can try to load the image from the disk (or database or wherever the images are) and dynamically include the best url in the page's image tag.

If you insist on doing it client-side, you can try loading multiple image tags:

```
<img src="file1.jpg" alt="" onerror="this.style.display='none'">
<img src="file2.jpg" alt="" onerror="this.style.display='none'">
<img src="file3.jpg" alt="" onerror="this.style.display='none'">
<img src="file4.jpg" alt="" onerror="this.style.display='none'">
<img src="file5.jpg" alt="" onerror="this.style.display='none'">
<img src="file6.jpg" alt="" onerror="this.style.display='none'">
```

This will result in a page that appears to have lots of images but they disappear as the page loads.  The `alt=""` is required to make Opera not show the broken image placeholder; the `onerror` is required for Chrome and IE.

If that's not spiffy enough, and if all your images are the same size, and that size is known, you could stack a bunch of images one on top of the other, so that the first image that loads hides all the others.  This worked for me in Opera, FF, and IE8.  It loads the last image in the list that exists.  Note that this wastes bandwidth and memory because every image is loaded.

```
<div style="width: 50px; height:38px; background-image: url(file1.jpg);">
<div style="width: 50px; height:38px; background-image: url(file2.jpg);">
<div style="width: 50px; height:38px; background-image: url(file3.jpg);">
<div style="width: 50px; height:38px; background-image: url(file4.jpg);">
<div style="width: 50px; height:38px; background-image: url(file5.jpg);">
<div style="width: 50px; height:38px; background-image: url(file6.jpg);">
<div style="width: 50px; height:38px; background-image: url(file7.jpg);">
</div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Finally, there is the JavaScript approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var image_array = ['file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg', 'file3.jpg', 'file4.jpg', 'file5.jpg','file6.jpg' ];
      function load_img(imgId, image, images, index) {
        image.onerror = function() {
          load_img(imgId, this, images, index+1);
        };
        image.onload  = function() {
          var element = document.getElementById(imgId); 
          if (element) {
            element.src = this.src; 
            element.style.display = 'block';
          }
        };  
        image.src = images[index];
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="id_1" alt="" style="display: none;">
  </body>
  <script>
        load_img('id_1', new Image(), image_array, 0);
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: The javascript solution results in an infinite loop if none of the images exist. You need to add `if (index >= images.length) return;` as the first line of the `load_img(..)` function.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying setting multiple sources to the image tag depending on the resolution, srcset is the paramenter you're looking for.

```
<img src="images/space-needle.jpg"
srcset="images/space-needle.jpg 1x, images/space-needle-2x.jpg 2x,
images/space-needle-hd.jpg 3x">
```

Answer (score 3):

If I am reading the specification correctly, you should be able to do this with the [HTML `object` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/objects.html#h-13.3). `<object>` tags can be nested and thereby provide a chain of resources that are tried each in turn to be rendered and upon failure the user agent continues with the next one.

Note, though, that this behaviour is/was buggy for several browsers and versions.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it still isn't really usable thanks to poor support in current IE versions. +1 for the way it was *supposed* to be done though.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304133%28VS.85%29.aspx it works as of IE 7, although the DOM was faulty back then. MS claims it's fully supported in IE 8, including DOM accessibility for disabled nested objects.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the browser being able to retrieve some content with an HTTP response code 200 for a specific URL, then the answer is : NO from the client side using only HTML.

In other words, you can't have an element (e.g. img) and specify multiple URLs to "try".

Of course you can craft something on the server side: a request comes in for resource X and the server has a list of URLs that "work".

Answer (score 1):

INAJNBAM (I'm not a Javascript Ninja by any means), but in **pseudo code**, maybe try something like this after the page has loaded: (OR, now that I think about it, this would work well with PHP too)

```
$images = array('img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.png'....)
    foreach $images as $img
        {if $img.height > 0px
            {print "<img src="$img" />"
            end}
        };;;;
```

In fact PHP would be even better because I presume in JS this would result in images flashing up on the screen at the end of the pageload. Try it out in PHP and see if something like this fits your bill.

**NOTE**: I added 4 semi colons at the end. I know Javascript always wants 'em, I just didn't know where to stick them.

Answer (score 1):

If by saying "works" you mean the image can be loaded, you can use the "load" function on an image( in your case a bunch of images) of jQuery and inside of it declare the functionality that will be fire once the loading of the an image is completed.

If by saying "works" you mean that the HTTP status code is ok then use an ajax call using jquery.

```
function getUrlStatus(url) {
     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         complete: function(xhr) {
             return xhr.status;
         }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could enter the URL of some server-side application/script that serves up the image from whatever image source it can find.

You could do this in ASP.Net with an HTTPHandler that sends a response of content-type=image/jpg.

Other than ASP.Net there are amny other server-side options such as Perl, PHP...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider the HTML <picture> element ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)).

Wrap the <picture> element around and <img> element and any number of / elements. The browser will select a source element that it is best suited from the list and ignore the rest. The final <img> element determines the size and shape of the picture and provides a fallback for browsers that do not support the <picture> element. The MDN article I linked describes a number of scenarios, but the scenario below is one that I use to get a browser to choose the best image format it can handle using the **srcset** and **type** attributes:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="photo.jxl" type="image/jxl" />
    <source srcset="photo.avif" type="image/avif" />
    <source srcset="photo.webp" type="image/webp" />
    <img src="photo.jpg" alt="My photo" />
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

For two images, this worked for me. I tested by blocking my first source host with firewall and it showed the other source.

```
 <img src="image1" onerrer="src='image2'">
```