# how to show alternate image if source image is not found? (onerror working in IE but not in mozilla)

Tags: javascript, html, image

I need to show an alternate image in cell of table if source image is not found.
Currently below code is used to do so.

```
cell.innerHTML="<img height=40 width=40 src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/writeImage.htm' onError='ImgErrorVideo(this);'>" 
function ImgErrorVideo(source){
        source.src = "video.png";
        source.onerror = ""; 
        return true; 
}
```

Now the problem is that the above is solution is working in Internet Explorer but not in mozilla.

Please tell me some solution which works in all browsers.

Comment: Indent code by 4 spaces. Also, if the code above is what you have, you have an error with a missing double quote at the end of innerHTML.

Comment: I forgot to put the double quote at the end here. The solution given in #3938383, there is one link mentioned over there in reply which is not working.

Comment: Another tip: When you reply to someone, start the comment with @ followed by their name, and they get a message that you have replied.

Comment: @some - when the intellisense finds and autocompletes the remaining characters in their name, it leaves the "@johntrepreneur" text in the comment, but sometimes the intellisense doesn't trigger when typing a reply comment to the user and strips it from the comment. Not sure if they get notified or not, but it's annoying and makes answers with lots of comments hard to read. Why does it only work sometimes or for some of the users???

Comment: please refer the correct answer, i have the same problem

Answer (score 449):

I think this is very nice and short

```
<img src="imagenotfound.gif" alt="Image not found" onerror="this.src='imagefound.gif';" />
```

But, be careful. The user's browser will be stuck in an endless loop if the onerror image itself generates an error.

---

**EDIT**
To avoid endless loop, remove the `onerror` from it at once.

```
<img src="imagenotfound.gif" alt="Image not found" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='imagefound.gif';" />
```

By calling `this.onerror=null` it will remove the onerror then try to get the alternate image.

---

**NEW**
I would like to add a jQuery way, if this can help anyone.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".backup_picture").on("error", function(){
        $(this).attr('src', './images/nopicture.png');
    });
});
</script>

<img class='backup_picture' src='./images/nonexistent_image_file.png' />
```

You simply need to add class='backup_picture' to any img tag that you want a backup picture to load if it tries to show a bad image.

Comment: @Etashou - Chrome only triggers the `onerror` event one time unlike all other browsers.

Comment: not working in mozilla, getting error of wrong syntax on this.src

Comment: Not Working in Firefox & other browser, What to do for the others

Comment: For me with firefox it works well for a long time (since the post). Do you have any demo where it doesn't and where we could look at it.

Comment: jQuery method works on Chrome for multiple loads to the same img element

Comment: Word of warning: I thought that since "delete this.onerror" works on IE, it would work everywhere, but it actually had no effect in Firefox which led to hundreds of thousands of 404 calls to the image server. As the OP says, "this.onerror = null" is the way to go.

Comment: Just letting you guys know that `$().error()` is deprecated on jQuery 1.8. 
Use `$().on("error", function(){});` instead

Comment: Or even better `$().on('error', function () { ... });` to only attempt to load the backup image once. Otherwise if your backup image fails to load, the client browser will continue to fire the handler over and over again.

Comment: `Chrome only triggers the onerror event one time`

Not true today, it's falling to endless loop.

Comment: @Etdashou thank you! I am using php and I have tried everything and nothing has worked until your JS.

Comment: Anyone have any idea if having backup images like this positively impacts SEO?

Answer (score 4):

I have got the solution for my query:

i have done something like this:

```
cell.innerHTML="<img height=40 width=40 alt='' src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/writeImage.htm?' onerror='onImgError(this);' onLoad='setDefaultImage(this);'>"

function setDefaultImage(source){
        var badImg = new Image();
        badImg.src = "video.png";
        var cpyImg = new Image();
        cpyImg.src = source.src;

        if(!cpyImg.width)
        {
            source.src = badImg.src;
        }

    }


    function onImgError(source){
        source.src = "video.png";
        source.onerror = ""; 
        return true; 
    }
```

This way it's working in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to a PHP solution:

```
<td><img src='<?PHP
  $path1 = "path/to/your/image.jpg";
  $path2 = "alternate/path/to/another/image.jpg";

  echo file_exists($path1) ? $path1 : $path2; 
  ?>' alt='' />
</td>
```

////EDIT 
OK, here's a JS version:

```
<table><tr>
<td><img src='' id='myImage' /></td>
</tr></table>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  document.getElementById('myImage').src = "newImage.png";

  document.getElementById('myImage').onload = function() { 
    alert("done"); 
  }

  document.getElementById('myImage').onerror = function() { 
    alert("Inserting alternate");
    document.getElementById('myImage').src = "alternate.png"; 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i need to do this only by javascript. Please tell me if there is any solution for this.