# alt attribute for Image tag in html

Tags: javascript, html, image, alt

Scenario:

```
 <img src="filepath" alt="image not found">
```

This will make sure that if the file is not found in the path then the text would be loaded .....

Question:
Instead of a alternative text can a image be loaded ?? is there any tags would readily serve my purpose and is there any custom javascript functions which could be given in #alt tag??

Comment: An image cannot be loaded instead. (What guarantee do you have that *that* image would be found and loaded? Would you then want to set an alt image for the alt image? etc.)

Comment: Please note that the `alt` attribute is basically an accessibility feature. In an environment where images cannot be displayed (e.g. a screen reader), another image is not an adequate replacement. I suggest you use the attribute for the intended purpose (provide a brief description of the picture if applicable, which "image not found" isn't) and find another way to detect missing pictures.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984287/how-to-show-alternate-image-if-source-image-is-not-found-onerror-working-in-ie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special event wich allow you to make this. It's :

```
<img src="" onerror="this.src='path/to/default'" />
```

Comment: <img src="" onerror=this.src="path of the img">' can this be used..if so how to use it in inner html ??

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the image loaded in JavaScript:

```
var img = document.getElementById('image');
if ( img.complete && img.naturalWidth == 0 ) {
  // some error, load alternate image:
  img.src = "path to alternative img";
}
```

---

**Edit:** Complete solution (using `onerror` from @JoDev's answer) would be:

```
<script>
function validate (img) {
  // Clear the callback to avoid infinite loop in case
  // new image path would be also invalid.
  img.onerror = null;

  if ( img.complete && img.naturalWidth == 0 ) {
    // some error, load alternate image:
    img.src = "http://example.com/valid_path.png";
  }
}
</script>

<img onerror="javascript:validate(this);" 
     src="http://example.com/some_invalid_path.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code..

Inside onerror function add src path which you want load. If src is image is loaded.

```js
<img onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='http://www.personal.psu.edu/oeo5025/jpg.jpg'" id="ddd" 
src='http://www.loveimagesdownload.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/declaration-of-love_23-2147517078.jpg'/>
```