# how to show a default image Incase the Image is found

Tags: jquery

I will be getting a JSON response from a server

```
var  imagesdata = 
{
    "images": [
        {
            "image": "JSON_images/popcorn.jpg",
            "name": "Popcorn"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ice creams",
            "image": "JSON_images/icecream_cup.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Snacks & Corn",
            "image": "JSON_images/puff_egg.jpg"
        },
        {
            "image": "JSON_images/thumsup_can.jpg",
            "name": "Soft Drinks"
        }
    ]
}





  for (var i = 0; i &lt; imagesdata.images.length; i++) {
        var imagename = imagesdata.images[i].image;
        var name = imagesdata.images[i].name;
        callImage(imagename, name);
    }

    function callImage(imagename, name) {
        var divhtml = $('<div class="item">');
        divhtml.append('<i><img class = "imgclss" id="' + name + '" src="' + imagename + '" alt=""/></i>');
        divhtml.append('</div>');
    }
```

With the above JSON Data i am showing the images dynmaically on the User Interface as shown below and the User Interface looks this way

[image]

My question is that in case a particular  image is not found under the JSON_images , **how can i show a default image** ??

Comment: Declare 'not found'? Would that be an empty `image` property in the JSON or a path to a nonexisting image?

Comment: sorry , i ddin't get you , could you please elobrate ??

Comment: Maybe a mistake in the title? Do you mean `not found` ? In this case, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984287/how-to-show-alternate-image-if-source-image-is-not-found-onerror-working-in-ie

Comment: What I meant was: will you be getting this: `{"image": "", "name": "Soft Drinks"}` or this `{"image": "nonexistingimage.jpg", "name": "Soft Drinks"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean if your using jquery, you can do either one, find the one which has an error and replace it with an missing image or hide it.

```
// Replace source
$('img').error(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'missing.png');
});
```

or

```
// Or, hide them
$("img").error(function(){
        $(this).hide();
});
```

---

JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/zm3qndxo/

Comment: Thank you very much , but when i added this inside my code $('img').error(function(){
       
alert('missing imagee');   nothing got fired up .

});

Comment: @PreethiJain edited my existing post with a jsfiddle