# Uncaught ReferenceError: emptyimage is not defined

Tags: javascript

Incase a img is not found , i am showing an alternate default image this way

```
var defaultimage = "images/emptyimage.jpg";


divhtml.append('<i><img class = "imgclss" id="'+name+'" src="'+imagename+'" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='+defaultimage+'"/></i>');
```

But in browser console , i am getting this undefined error

**Uncaught ReferenceError: emptyimage is not defined**

could anybody please help me how to resolve this errors?

I was folowing this link to resolve the issue

[how to show alternate image if source image is not found? (onerror working in IE but not in mozilla)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984287/how-to-show-alternate-image-if-source-image-is-not-found-onerror-working-in-ie)

Comment: show the full code, you are using `emptyimage` as string why it should throw an error, are you missing anything.

Comment: That code doesn't use a variable of that name so it wouldn't give that error.

Comment: There is nothing like emptyimage in the code .

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle with more context

Comment: Incase if i put var defaultimage = "images/home-logo.jpg"; , its giving home is not defined . :)

Comment: that's why I said show the full code.

Comment: This shows you why inline event handlers are a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is here :

```
onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='+defaultimage+'"
```

After the interpretation, it look like this :

```
onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=images/emptyimage.jpg"
```

You need to wrap your variable to make it a string once the javascript interpreted :

```
onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=\''+defaultimage+'\'"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var defaultimage = new Image();
defaultimage.src = "images/emptyimage.jpg";

// define `name` and `imagename`

divhtml.append('<i><img class="imgclss" id="'+name+'" src="'+imagename+'" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='+defaultimage.src+'"/></i>');
```

Comment: Thanks , but why its giving Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score -1):

How do I fix uncaught ReferenceError is not defined?

Answer: Execute Code after jQuery Library has Loaded

The most common reason behind the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" is executing the jQuery code before the jQuery library file has loaded. Therefore make sure that you're executing the jQuery code only after jQuery library file has finished loading.