# If image isn't avaiable display image placeholder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hey guys I am pulling images to my front end using this PHP:

```php
echo '<img class="ms-thumb" src="'.(explode(',', $cardata["PictureRefs"])[0]).'" alt="'.$cardata["Variant"].'" />';
```

So I'm taking images from my database and displaying them in a list, in rare cases some SQL rows wont have an image url.

Can anyone show me an example of code that I could use to display a placeholder image if the src="" is empty?

I'm not great with JS and I'm guessing I'll need to use it to accomplish this.

Any example of how this could be done would be great.

Comment: Looking for some stuff like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984287/how-to-show-alternate-image-if-source-image-is-not-found-onerror-working-in-ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit simple line, this will place image if image is empty (not there). replace src attribute with this one

```
   src="'.(!empty( $cardata["PictureRefs"]))?(explode(',', $cardata["PictureRefs"])[0]):'img/placeholder.jpg' .'"
```

where your path to img is

'img/placeholder.jpg'

change it to your placeholder path

Comment: I've just tried using the code and I'm getting a syntax error, any ideas why?

<img class="ms-thumb" src="'.(!empty( $cardata["PictureRefs"])):(explode(',', $cardata["PictureRefs"])[0])?'/db-content/theme/media/img/no-image.jpg' .'" alt="'.$cardata["Variant"].'" />

Comment: This is the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: have you edited my code or it is itself giving error?