# Backup img if the first can't be found on HTML

Tags: html, http-status-code-404

I want to display img1.png. However, if there's an error finding the file, I want the backup missing.png to appear instead. Is there a way in HTML to have if statements or exceptions?

```
<try>?
    <img src="img1.png">
<except error 404>?
    <img src="missing.png">
```

I put a question mark on all the lines that I don't understand what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9891041/3168859)

It says you can do it as below

```
<img src="img1.png" alt="Image not found" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='missing.png';" />
```

where `onerror` is a Javascript function. Please refer the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) for more details about `onerror`