# how to replace image source in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

Could you please tell me how to replace image source in react? .I am setting a `src` url to my `img` tag.
If image is not present on server I want to replace `src` url to this one `http://punemirror.indiatimes.com/photo/55813567.cms`

if image is present on server then it fine .if not then I need to change source url to "http://punemirror.indiatimes.com/photo/55813567.cms
"

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/KOrGKp3B8

I try like that

```
imageExists(url, callback) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            callback(true);
        };
        img.onerror = function () {
            callback(false);
        };
        img.src = url;
    }


    renderList() {
        const lis = this.items.map((item, key) => {
            var src = "http://mumbaimirror.indiatimes.com/photo/" + item.id + ".cms";
            const alt = "http://punemirror.indiatimes.com/photo/55813567.cms";

            return (
                <li key={key}>
                    <a><img src={src}/><span>{item.hl}</span></a>
                </li>
            )
        })
        return (
            <ul>
                {lis}
            </ul>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="list">
                {this.renderList()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984287/how-to-show-alternate-image-if-source-image-is-not-found-onerror-working-in-ie

Answer (score 2):

Check if your image exists, [use this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837735/check-if-image-exists-on-server-using-javascript) and then in your component class :

```
componentWillMount() {
  var url = "http://mumbaimirror.indiatimes.com/photo/" + item.id + ".cms";
  const alt = "http://punemirror.indiatimes.com/photo/55813567.cms";
  var src = this.imageExists(url) ? url : alt;
  this.setState({ src });
}

// added from the mentioned post
function imageExists(image_url){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status != 404;
}

render() {
    var src = this.state.src;
    ...
}
```

Comment: According to post - imageExists is async - therefore you cant call it in render.

Comment: @Amid The first snippet in the accepted answer of the mentioned post is sync.

Comment: @Fawas how does this relates/helps to the fact that OP explicitly specified in his question that `imageExists` method is accepting callback argument?

Comment: @Amid That's exactly the point in mentioning the other post. My solution uses a sync method when as compared to OPs callback approach.

Comment: Thanks @Fawaz for updating the post. The only problem with this approach is that if the list of images will be more that several or internet connection is week - sync checking will freeze the UI and make application unresponsive.

Comment: Agree @Amid. While this may suffice for the question asked, but for many images it should be async and update UI on callback with setState.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object for this.

```
<object data={src} type="image/png">
  <img src="http://punemirror.indiatimes.com/photo/55813567.cms" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

On component render, you need to check server-side for all present files, and return an array of all file `ids` you got on the server.

When you get that array of existing files, let's call it `allFileIds`, you just need to do :

```
<li key={key}>
                <a><img src={allFileIds.indexOf(item.id) !== -1 ? src : alt}/><span>{item.hl}</span></a>
</li>
```

This will check if the required `id` was found on the server (it checks if the `item.id` value exists in the array of file `ids` that your server returned), and if not, render the `alt` property instead of the `src`. I hope that was clear!

Answer (score 0):

First put your image collection in state instead of field.

I assume each image in your images collection contains at least one field: url. You can check your images (this.items) for existence in componentDidMount/componentWillReceiveProps. Note that your `imageExists` method is async - therefore you cant use it during rendering. Based on the check you can set img.src to be either undefined/null or valid URL.

Then in render check image.url and if it is missing - use default one.

Comment: I cleared but I am trying to implement this ..if you share some code then it is benefit  to me