# How to replace image with effect with React?

Tags: css, reactjs, image, effects

I have the following code -

```
render() {
    return <DeviceThemeProvider><GlobalStyle /><div>
            <div class="grids">
                <div id="grid">
                    <div class="grid-element">
                        <img class="displayed" src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/692.png'} />
                    </div>
```

Now I would like to replace the image 692.png with 693.png.
[I understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369090/how-to-replace-image-source-in-react) how to do with `setState`/`src`. But how to do it with some effect? Fade out/fade in? I found CSS `transition` property. Could it be used with React somehow?

What if I need to replace it with `no image` and replace `no image` with 692.png?

Comment: You check this http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition?

Comment: Without using external library, it is possible actually @TusharShahi

Comment: But replacing image with transition is a bit difficult task than having multiple images, and switching from one to another using transition. I prefer the latter

Comment: @TusharShahi, thank you. I've used http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/switch-transition from the same group - it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TusharShahi I used http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/switch-transition library.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, majority of the browsers supports:

```css
.cat {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: background 1s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6jwqkes3/1/

! But this is not included in the standard.