# rewriting a function to a boolean

Tags: javascript, image

hi guys I have this function:
its checking if the image URL is an actual image, but I want to change it , instead of console log I want it to return true or false,

```js
function checkImage(url) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.send();
  request.onload = function() {
    status = request.status;
    if (request.status == 200) //if(statusText == OK)
    {
      console.log("image exists");
    } else {
      console.log("image doesn't exist");
    }
  }
}
checkImage("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
```

I want checkImage to return True/False instead of console logging, but when i write return true or false, that doesn't seem to work, 
anyone knows why?

Comment: The `.onload` function won't actually be called until the HTTP request completes, and that will be long after `checkImage()` has returned.

Comment: so I should do it async?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: In what context are you trying to use the checkImage function?

Comment: @Tekill I'm making a website when users can add an image to their profile, I want to check if the image exists and then show it or put a default picture if it doesnt.

Comment: Why can't you just return true and return false instead of the console.log() and store the checkImage function result into a variable or check it inside a if statement.

Comment: @RonnyRules Check the possible duplicate (and the other question mentioned in the accepted answer) for the answer.

Comment: @RonnyRules I tried that, didn't work

Comment: @AlexK it already is asynchronous.

Comment: @Andreas If I insert a "https:google.com" URL, will the image exist aswell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the whole purpose of this function is to check if the image exists with the intent of displaying a default image I would use a much simpler approach. Why not use the following method:

```html
<img src="imagenotfound.gif" alt="Image not found" onerror="this.src='imagefound.gif';" />
```

This is described at further length [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984287/how-to-show-alternate-image-if-source-image-is-not-found-onerror-working-in-ie)

Answer (score 2):

Just change the console to callback may help u solve it

```
function checkImg(url,success,error){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.send();
request.onload = function() {
status = request.status;
if (request.status == 200) //.if(statusText == OK)
{
  success && success()
} else {
  error && error()
}
```

}
}

Replace the Ajax with Image.onload()